# How to change radiobutton style in alertDialog

Tags: android, dialog, radio-button, themes

I am working on an Android application where I would like to change the color of the RadioButton inside AlertDialogs. I want those RadioButtons to match my application theme.

So I guessed that I should look for an Android attribute that defines the drawables of my RadioButtons and modify it inside my theme.

First I found out that the AlertDialog uses CheckedTextView to display the RadioButton. In the layout select_dialog_singlechoice_holo.xml i found this:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    ...
/>
```

I then went to the themes.xml and looked in Holo.Light theme to find this:

```
<item name="listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@android:drawable/btn_radio_holo_light</item>
```

So in my theme i changed the latter to this:

```
<style name="GreenTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >

    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/green_radio_button</item>

</style>
```

Unfortunately nothing happened.

What did I miss?

Comment: How did you set your application theme?

Comment: In the manifest!  android:theme="@style/GreenTheme"

Comment: Just checking to make sure you didn't miss the obvious.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround. It seems that alertDialog is somehow overriding listChoiceIndicatorSingle attribute. So my solution was to add an ArrayAdapter when creating the choices thus overriding the layout that will be used by the alertDialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
String[] items= getResources().getStringArray(choices);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, items);

builder.setSingleChoiceItems(adapter, checkedItem, listener);
```